# Ignore Primary key when serialize using Gson

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, android-room

I am doing an export/import solution for my app using GSON, and saving on ExternalStorage. I want to serialize all field except the `PrimaryKey`. When deserializing and adding the Items to db I want the `PrimaryKey` auto-generated.

The one solution I have found is to use **@Transient** but is that a good solution or does it have any downsides? Any other suggestions?

```
@Entity(tableName = "item")
data class Item(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "data", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.BLOB) val DataItem: FloatArray,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "created_at") var createdAt: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
) {
    @Transient @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: Int = 0
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see some side effects - transient make filed totally unserializable (for example when is set as `argument` in bundle, assuming your `Item` would be `Serializable`), not only for GSON.

So, one of possibility I see is to add SerializationStrategy for GSON:

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey
import com.google.gson.FieldAttributes
import com.google.gson.ExclusionStrategy
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import com.google.gson.Gson


GsonBuilder()
    .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(object : ExclusionStrategy {
        override fun shouldSkipField(f: FieldAttributes): Boolean {
            return f.annotations.any { it is PrimaryKey }
        }

        override fun shouldSkipClass(aClass: Class<*>): Boolean {
            return false
        }
    }
).create()
```

But, it would not serialize every field annotated with `@PrimaryClass`. The other way would be use `@Expose` with param `serialize = false`:

`@Expose(serializable = false) @PrimaryKey var id: Int = 0`

Then the filed will be excluded from serialization.
You can see docs of `Expose` here: https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html